# Europe on a very tight budget

Tags: budget, europe, tips-and-tricks, backpacking, hitchhiking

I am planning to go for a tour around Europe for one month. Must visit countries: UK-Germany-Austria-Hungary-Italy-Switzerland-France. I read a lot about feed that encourage people to go for Eurail or any Global Pass trains.

Is there any other option for a tight-budget backpacker to save on this trip?

Is there any cheap local bus that I can hop on and off between cities?

I am not good in planning ahead and I always prefer to travel on a sudden situation.

Will €800 be enough?

I don't mind sleeping or CouchSurfing or even hitchhiking.

Is it safe to hitchhike in Europe?

Comment: Hi Shaf IEe and welcome to Travel SE. Your question is quite vague and broad at the moment and also contains several subquestions. Could you elaborate a little bit more context and think about splitting the question up in multiple questions. Otherwise, we have to close this question.

Comment: The "cheap transport ticket other than train" and "is it save to hitchhike" are two separate questions.

Comment: It is ok to hitchhike, but people don't really take hitchhikers any more (Hungary, Italy). Check the hitchwiki, maybe they have newer information.

Answer (score 2):

I never tried it but I heard [MegaBus](http://uk.megabus.com/) is quite cheap and they are currently in:

- United Kingdom
- France
- Netherlands
- Belgium.

Comment: You need to book a long way in advance to get their very cheapest deals, which might not work well for someone who doesn't plan ahead...

Comment: Also try Eurolines. Quite cheap. And of course Ryanair, but be careful, they usually are quite far from city centers.